# How can prove limit of $ n\sin(\frac{1}{n})=1 $ as $ n $ approaches to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve this sequence limit

$\lim_{n\to \infty} $ $n\sin(\frac{1}{n})=1$

and I’m struggling finding a bound for $|a_n -l|$

I thought of rewriting

$|n\sin(\frac{1}{n}) - 1|$

As

$|\frac {\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}} - 1|$

An then maybe rewrite 1 as

$|\frac {\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}} - \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}|$

But I don’t know how to continue and find $\epsilon$

I would appreciate some help and thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use L'Hopital for $\sin(x)/x$.

Comment: There are many characterizations of the sine function (e.g., power series representation, the inverse of $f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt$.  How do you define $\sin(x)$?  See [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1/2046827#2046827)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).